# Tab stacking/groups plugin for Firefox, that is similar to Opera's?

Tags: firefox

Opera (at least until version 12) had this great feature that let me drag a tab on top of another tab and form a stacking "group" that could retract when not needed and only take up the space of one tab.

Is there a plugin for Firefox that I can use to replicate this behavior?

Note that Firefox's *tab groups* is not what I am looking for, as it completely isolates the group from the rest of my tabs.

This is what I'm talking about:

"Closed" stack:

[image]

"Expanded" stack:

[image]

Comment: *Is there...*: Yes, definitely. Not using it myself, but I saw it a while ago at Mozilla addons: it grouped tabs using different colors and "tiny spaces" around the group if I remember correctly. Is that what you're after? If so, I might find it again.

Comment: @Izzy Not quite. I've added some screenshots I took from Opera to demonstrate.

Comment: [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) is somewhat like this, though it's a bit different.

Comment: @Compro01 That isn't really what I want. The whole idea was to free up space on the tab bar, hiding groups of tabs I don't need to look at all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I am also strugguling without Opera 12. I am thinking about to switch to FF.
The [Tab Utilities](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/) plugin is the closest I found. Check out its [development versions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/versions/). To enable Opera tabs style go to *about:config* and set to true this property **`extensions.tabutils.dragToStack`**.

Comment: I did try that plugin, but (at least on FF 31) it is quite buggy. The colours glitch in and out with the rest of my tab bar (and some blue) and the stack always opens and closes when a Ctrl+Tab over it. Perhaps that is just because the extension hasn't been updated beyond FF 28 yet?

Comment: Did you try to use the latest beta version? Also check [this](https://github.com/ithinc/tabutils/wiki/Tab-Stacking-options) page. I set **extensions.tabutils.dragToStack** to true and **extensions.tabutils.colorStack** to false and also disabled all colorification features. It looks ok now.

Comment: How would I edit those?

Comment: open about:config page in ff and find those properties

Answer (score 2):

[Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) is another option.

The default changes the tab bar to the left but you can reset it to the top in the options of the addon.